# How to list undergraduate paper on CV

Tags: publications, mathematics, cv, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

- Mathematics.
- Not novel research ~ merely an analysis / reformulation of an existing, proved theorem
- Not a thesis, but was a major (50%) component of a senior course.
- Never published.
- The math isn't even advanced - it's actually quite basic - but it's fun!

(a) *Should* I even mention this on a CV?

(b) If I should, how would I go about doing so? How to site it? Host and provide link?

Comment: I think it depends on where you are at now in life. Did you just finish undergraduate work? Are you finishing a Masters degree and applying for a non-academic job? Are you finishing a Ph.D.? Are you tenure-track or tenured, and seeking to switch universities?

Answer (score 4):

The paper alone isn't worthy of your CV. It's not a peer-reviewed publication, which is about the closest place it would fit. You could list the senior project under your education section to provide an idea of your area of focus, but the paper alone doesn't carry any weight. I had a senior capstone project in my undergraduate curriculum, and I have listed the project as sort of my undergraduate "thesis", but not referring to any text.

Comment: +1 for suggestion of describing it in the 'education' section to basically show interests/specialties. Depending on what your CV is going for - if it is useful for someone to check your writing skills or your ability to put something together logically and finish a project, that would be the primary reason to post it somewhere and provide a link on CV. This could be good even in applications to grad schools/stuff to professor.

Comment: This is probably an outlier, but if I had an undergraduate honors thesis like Gaebler's [*Large Cardinals and Projective Determinacy*](https://harvard.academia.edu/JohannGaebler), I'd find some place for it on my CV unless I was at least a mid-career academic!

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned the paper alone is not really worth mentioning if it is not published, except to show your field of interest.

Therefore I would suggest to get in published. There are (even reviewed) student [journals/conferences](http://www.cur.org/resources/students/undergraduate_journals/) which would be a good fit for that. Maybe some extra work is required to get it accepted but I think it would definitely be worth it if you are in an early career stage.