# Does an internal report count as a publication?

Tags: citations, research-undergraduate

I worked in an academic laboratory for several months for an undergraduate research experience. The results of my project were not novel enough to be published in a journal. However, I wrote a 50-page report that detailed my project (technical details of the experimental apparatus, design considerations, important calculations, etc).

The report is meant to be a reference for future members of the lab.

1. Does this count as a "publication" that I could put on my graduate school applications? It is not peer-reviewed except for having been read over by the lab PI and other lab members.
2. Is this type of document commonly considered a 'technical report', 'internal report', 'scientific report', or by some other name?
3. I authored the report by myself but other members of the lab helped extensively with the project. If I list it under "publications", should I put only my name or the names of all those who contributed to the project?

I am planning to upload the report to my public web page, but it is not otherwise hosted online.

Comment: see comments also in https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/91744/how-to-list-undergraduate-paper-on-cv

Answer (score 4):

> Does this count as a "publication" that I could put on my graduate school applications? It is not peer-reviewed except for having been read over by the lab PI and other lab members.

Normally CVs have areas for journal articles, conferences, and "unrefereed publications".  I would think the same would be true of an application.  Certainly worth listing.

> Is this type of document commonly considered a 'technical report', 'internal report', 'scientific report', or by some other name?

Usually this depends on the institution.  If you called it a technical report, it's a technical report.  If you didn't call it anything, I'd say "internal report, XYZ lab" sounds about right.

> I authored the report by myself but other members of the lab helped extensively with the project. If I list it under "publications", should I put only my name or the names of all those who contributed to the project?

If you were the sole author listed in the report, you should list yourself as the sole author when putting it on the CV/application.  Perhaps you should have included coauthors; if so, if it's not too late, maybe you can amend & reissue it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Seconding @Fred Douglis' answer (which I tried to do in a comment, but it mysteriously evaporated... not the first time): you should exactly tell what you have done. That is, tell the truth, as opposed to worrying about fitting the truth into some artifactual conventional categories. That is, tell the work you have done. Obviously. It may not be earth-shattering, or anything that would be status-enhancing when you're 50 years old, but that's not the point. The point is that you have done work. (And, on this site, I wonder what it is that is happening that what I imagine to be meaningful comments disappear without a trace... )

(In brief, this will not "count" as a "publication" in the ultra-commodified sense, since by those standards it simply isn't. But it is work that you have done, and if you are not embarrassed to present it to the world then you should... present it to the world. The conventional rules about what is status-enhancing or not are vestiges of old things... but, true, even then, people were subliminally oh-so-much aware of status. Surely this is not like other human endeavors, eh! :)

Comment: Formal SE policy on comments is that they are meant to be strictly for comments that are clarifying the question ("Are you in the US?"; "What ring are your matrices over?"). Everything else, especially a (mini-)answer, is considered inappropriate as a comment. Less popular sites don't moderate this that strictly, but the more popular the site becomes the more fiercely this is enforced (and usually with good reason; comments aren't as well-moderated by the community as answers, and dozens can quickly accumulate). That said, often they are needlessly and lazily aggressive in their culls.

Answer (score 0):

That certainly sounds like a substantial project, but I would not consider it a publication, even an un-refereed one, especially because you are not clear about the appropriate authorship (which suggests it is not in the polished state that even a non-peer-reviewed publication would be in).

I would instead suggest listing it as one of the deliverables when you note your research/work experience on your application. Although you want to highlight this experience, I fear that including it as some sort of publication may make it seem like you are trying to pad your resume and you would have to be careful to present it clearly as not an academic publication. Doing so is even more difficult if you don't have another publication that *is* an academic work.

As an undergraduate, it isn't necessarily expected that you will produce an academic publication. Research experience by itself can be an asset.

Also, only do this:

> I am planning to upload the report to my public web page, but it is not otherwise hosted online.

..if you have permission to do so from your PI.